# In R, how do save space with running a function on 192 dataframes?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, vector

I have around 192 CSV's that I have converted to dataframes. I would like to be able to put the names of each dataframe in a vector and then run a FOR LOOP through the vector like so:

```
for (i in length(vector)){
vector[i] <- f1(vector[i])
}
```

or just pass through the vector into the function like so: f1(vector).

If the vector is full of integers or strings, I can put the vector through a function and it will work fine. For example:

```
squared <- function(x) {
 return(x*x)
}
```

This will work with with a vector `c(1,2,3,4,5)` and return `c(1,4,9,16,25)`. Otherwise, I have to make 124 lines of code for each function I want to do.

Your advice would be greatly appreciated, please.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Transforming all variables of all data frames by the same function?

Comment: @wusel One example of a function I am doing is converting this column of dates that are listed as a date range (11/2 - 11/15) to a string and then to a Date type. Running the function saves me about 14 lines of code because the function is 3 lines, and I am calling 7 times (21 - 7 = 14).

Comment: @TAG_You're_It If the below answers your  question, please feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the 'v' sign next to the top of the answer so that others see that the question has been resolved. Otherwise, please specify what issues remain.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most Rtistic way of doing it would be to have all your dataframes in a list to start with. For instance,

```
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- mtcars
df3 <- mtcars

frames <- grep('df', ls(), value = T)

frame_list <- lapply(frames, get)
```

gets you there. Now you can apply whatever function you want to each dataframe in a `lapply` call. So, for instance, if you wanted to get all the squared values of `mpg`, you could write

```
frame_adj <- lapply(frame_list, function(x) x$mpg * x$mpg )
```

The above gives you all the squared values of `mpg` from the original dataframes, but does not keep the other columns. If you prefer to keep the other values, simply adjust your function to return the dataframe, e.g.

```
frames_with_squared_mpg <- 
  lapply(frame_list, function(x) {
    x$mpg_sq <- x$mpg * x$mpg
    return(x)})
```

will get you there.